# Is there a way to activate the console while unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Pretty straightforward: I want to have the console display while I'm unit testing. Is there a way to turn this on directly, or do I have to use `AllocConsole`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests you can still call `Console.WriteLine` which will output content to the console. The end result of doing that is, all that content will appear in the test results window (`MSTest`) or, for example, the `Resharper` unit test runner.

In order to get real-time output, via the console window, you may have to experiment with, maybe, using the console test runner of your chosen testing framework. For example, if you're using `NUnit` then try using the `NUnit` console test runner and see what happens. The crux of it is that, out of the box, there is no `Visual Studio` support to do what you want (I believe this is the case).

Comment: Huh, so it sounds like I need to use `AllocConsole` then. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is to change the project type from class library to an executable application. Probably you still could run the tests, because all the test classes will be still present in the assembly and the console subsystem (or something) will be additionally present.

Comment: It's not super elegant because you have to introduce an entry point (`Main`), and you can't control it from the Test-Explorer but it does work.